# Horror comic where a character is tortured and his screams recorded?

Tags: story-identification, comics

I had a horror comic as a kid in 80s or early 90s that had a great premise. I believe it was an anthology type comic with multiple stories.

This showed a person being tortured by an author of horror stories. The author would hit the person that is restrained and record the noises he made for use in his works. Basically he would hit the person being tortured and the guy would scream some odd combination of syllables. The author would write them down and tell him to keep going and he would scream some additional odd-sounding gibberish word.
At the end the author thanked him for his help and said he did good screaming in pain. The person that was being tortured then said, 'Oh, I was not screaming in pain, I was screaming for help'. And that is when you realize he was screaming the names of various horrors from H.P. Lovecraft.
The final frame shows those horrors coming to kill the author.

That line about screaming for help has always stuck with me and I think is a great story element.
Anyone remember this?

Edit - Adding titles I recognize

Possibles:
The House of Mystery

Ghost Manor

Not possibles:
Twisted Tales - The story I remember was on low-quality paper stock

Comment: Might be one of these (warning: tvtropes link!) https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Creator/ECComics

Comment: @jo1storm These appear to be published much earlier than the comic I am thinking of.

Comment: There is a similar story in Tales from the crypt 36 but that one is too old also: https://2.bp.blogspot.com/x1QQQ32fUpDpcNyTFqe4JUkjRBBsXunNWQSSoPSqUiY5cpVuurBCl9Dt7MEhFTaA8xPx8f5iKarN=s1600?rhlupa=MTA5LjI0NS4xNTkuNzI=&amp;rnvuka=TW96aWxsYS81LjAgKFdpbmRvd3MgTlQgNi4zOyBXaW42NDsgeDY0OyBydjoxMDYuMCkgR2Vja28vMjAxMDAxMDEgRmlyZWZveC8xMDYuMA

Comment: @jo1storm That is a similar concept but the person being tortured actually calls out names like 'Yog Soggoth'. I have my comics in storage right now so it may take a while to get it figured out.